# How do I get TensorFlow's 'import_graph_def' to return Tensors

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, restore

If I attempt to import a saved [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org) graph definition with

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

with gfile.FastGFile(FLAGS.model_save_dir.format(log_id) + '/graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
x, y, y_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, 
                               return_elements=['data/inputs',
                                                'output/network_activation',
                                                'data/correct_outputs'],
                               name='')
```

the returned values are not `Tensor`s as expected, but something else: instead, for example, of getting `x` as

```
Tensor("data/inputs:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32)
```

I get

```
name: "data/inputs_1"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
    }
  }
}
```

That is, instead of getting the expected tensor `x` I get, `x.op`. This confuses me because the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#import_graph_def) seems to say I should get a `Tensor` (though there are a bunch of *or*s there that make it hard to understand).

How do I get `tf.import_graph_def` to return specific `Tensor`s that I can then use (e.g. in feeding the loaded model, or running analyses)?

Comment: The second line of code should be `from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile`.

Answer (score 6):

The names `'data/inputs'`, `'output/network_activation'` and `'data/correct_outputs'` are actually operation names. To get `tf.import_graph_def()` to return `tf.Tensor` objects, you should append the an output index to the operation name, which is typically `':0'` for single-output operations:

```
x, y, y_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, 
                               return_elements=['data/inputs:0',
                                                'output/network_activation:0',
                                                'data/correct_outputs:0'],
                               name='')
```